# Why is there a LF character in a file containing only one line ? (in Linux)

Tags: linux, file

Why should my file contain a '\n' if there is only one line in this file?

Comment: What do you mean? You can easily create a file with no `\n`.

Comment: ? A Windows© file ? Please do `$ dos2unix [file-name]`

Comment: no it's not a windows file, and what i mean is : i create a file, put "hello" in it for example and save it, then when i read the line in C, i find a '\n' character in the end of the line, even tho there is only one line ( i'm new at using files in linux so this kinda bugged me because it doesn't happen in windows)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The newline character is normally added to *end* lines, not just to separate them. May Unix tools consider text files that don't end in a newline as (mildly) suspicious, and by default add it in. But you can create files without final newline if you really want to.

Answer (score 1):

Some command-line tools (such as `cat`, `touch`) can be used to create zero-length files.  On the other hand, other tools by default (such as a plain `echo` without parameters) may create an "empty" file with just a newline.  So it depends on what tool was used (and sometimes what options were used).